# How to include zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463057/how-to-include-the-zend-framework) but somehow, I still don't understand how to include the zend framework.

Zend is located at `C:\wamp\zend-library\Zend` (this folder contains folders like "barcode", "cache", "db", "EventManager" and so on...)

My php include path is configured like this in php.ini: `include_path = ".;C:\wamp\zend-library\Zend"` (it is uncommented and the line doesn't start with `;`)

output of `echo get_include_path()` is `.;C:\wamp\zend-library\Zend`

When trying to run a piece of code where is:

```
$adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter(array(
    'driver' => 'Mysqli',
    'database' => 'zend_db_example',
    'username' => 'developer',
    'password' => 'developer-password'
 ));
```

I get only this error: `Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' not found in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 23`

I'm using a windows 7 machine, but somehow everywhere everybody is just writing:

> Your PHP include_path needs to contain the path to Zend Framework's library

but nobody gives an example how to set up the whole thing. Am I missing some vital information or I just don't understand the whole "simply include it in your path" thing?

Comment: Is this line "include_path = ".;C:\wamp\zend-library\Zend" uncommented?? You have shown it with semi-colon??

Comment: yes it is uncommented, because otherwise `echo get_include_path()` would not output the same thing, and that's what baffles me, also added more clarification

Comment: I think you can go through this link ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463057/how-to-include-the-zend-framework

Comment: yes i did go through that question, i even linked it in my question, but i don't seem to "get it"

Answer (score 2):

The 'Zend' folder is part of the library, so your include path should be `C:\wamp\zend-library`. You'll also need to have setup the autoloader (ZF or Composer) for your code example to work.

Comment: ooooh, nodoby mentioned that i have to include the other folder *and* setup the autoloader... do you have any examples of how to setup the autoloader (by any chance)?

Comment: Are you following a tutorial?

Comment: i looked at the tutorial, but it's not very specific a most of the time they just write "create this function like this 'new Object( ... params ...)'" and then i search 30-40 minutes through their documentation what are the parameters for that object. :(

Comment: The reason I asked is that most tutorials recommend installing ZF2 using Composer, which would take care of all of this for you. If you want to do it yourself, check this article http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/using-zendloaderautoloader/ . You should only need to do the small bit in the "Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader" section

Comment: Ok i will try it, i'm trying to use the zend framework because of their great library and migrating the whole project to zend would cost too much effort and money.
I'll report later if i had some luck :) thanks